# PHP Dynamic Breadcrumbs based on URL

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working on trying to get breadcrumbs to work correctly.

Right now they work, but the urls in the onclick are not correct.

```
<?php
//$url = strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'admin');
$url = strstr('/content/modal/admin/content/polls.php', 'admin'); // admin/content/polls.php
$parse_url = preg_replace('/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/', '', $url); // admin/content/polls

$array = explode("/", $parse_url);

$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal(\'' . $array[$counter] . '\')">' . $item . '</a> / ';
    $counter++;
}
```

This shows as:

```
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('admin')">admin</a> / 
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('content')">content</a> /
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('polls')">polls</a> /
```

The result I'm trying to archieve:

```
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('admin')">admin</a> / 
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('admin/content')">content</a> /
<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal('admin/content/polls')">polls</a> /
```

How can I edit my script so it works like the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of remarks

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal(\'' . $array[$counter] . '\')">' . $item . '</a> / ';
    $counter++;
}
```

Foreach can be used like

```
foreach($array AS $index => $value)
```

Meaning your $counter is not needed, you can simply use `$index`.

Furthermore, you now have `$counter++;` as a single line, however you can combine it with the line above:

```
    ... initializemodal(\'' . $array[$counter++] . '\')"...
```

Do note that if you put the `++` behind the variable, it will increase AFTER the variable has been used.

```
$i = 0;
echo $i++; // This will print 0
echo $i++; // This will print 1
$i = 0;
echo ++$i; // This will print 1
echo ++$i; // This will print 2
```

To answer your question, you need to store the previous paths.

```
$path = []
foreach($array as $value) {
    $path[] = $value; // This array will first contain only one item, then two, then three, etc.
    echo '<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal(\'' . implode('/', $path) . '\')">' . $item . '</a> / ';
}
```

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will glue all values in `$path`. First there is nothing to glue, so it will result in `admin`. The second iteration it will glue admin with content, and adds a `/` between them. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to glue all elements **up to current value of $counter**. Right now you are just using what `$counter` points to, so you always get the last element, but not the whole "path". You basically need another loop like (not tested):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    $tmp = [];
    for ($i=0; $i<=$counter; $i++) {
       $tmp[] = $array($i);
    }
    $path = implode('/', $tmp);
    echo '<a href="javascript:;"  onclick="initializemodal(\'' . $path . '\')">' . $item . '</a> / ';
    $counter++;
}
```